# How to configure apache tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat8

I have install **`jdk1.6.0_04 and I have also install apache-tomcat-8.0.9`** 
and I have set path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\bin;`
and CLASSPATH appache tomcat server 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\lib\servlet-api.jar;`

but still it's not working properly when i try to open apache tomcat server on web browser
web page is not available

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: Have you started your tomcat? There are some `.bat` files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin`

Comment: yah i have started startup.bat

Answer (score 2):

Set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_04" and CATALINA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.9" than go to %CATALINA_HOME%\bin and run startup.bat
All simple configuration in  %CATALINA_HOME%\conf\server.xml

Answer (score 1):

You need jdk1.7 + to run tomcat 8, if you are using jdk1.6, you need tomcat 7-.
See this: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

This make me remember back in collage, it took me 2 days to finish jdk/tomcat hello world, :) , what a good time it is.

Just make sure, open a command line, input `java --version` to check whether you jdk is configured well, and which version it is in use. Just to be sure, in some case you need to re-login or reboot to make your new configured jdk work.

Believe me, if you configured jdk well, you don't need to change anything of the tomcat, just unzip it, and start it, it would work, unless the port 8080 is already taken.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the installation folder of apache tomcat in your case as you said its

`C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin` and double click the `startup.bat`

Then go to web browser and type `http://localhost:8080` that should do the work

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up CATALINE_HOME = your tomcat Location
2. JAVA_HOME = your java (Version 6 or Seven).
3. Path = Same JAVA_HOME Java version path til bin.
4. At final run the startup.bat